# Return a response and file via servicestack

Tags: file, servicestack, response

I am working on a project where we have a database and a separate file system both stored on the same server and are accessed through service stack requests and responses.

The database contains the relevant metadata for a given file in the file system and as such we would like to be able to retrieve and store these files and documents simultaneously to prevent orphaned data.

Is is possible to return both a stream of data (file) and a response DTO in the same response? Similar to how `JsonServiceClient.PostFileWithRequest` allows for both a file and request DTO to be passed to the server. If it is possibly how would it be handled on both the server and client sides?

In my research so far most applications appear to just return either a response document or a stream and mostly through the use of `HttpResult`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no support for [MIME Multipart/mixed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Multipart_subtypes) responses which is primarily for Email and rarely supported and used for HTTP. The easiest way to send additional metadata with your File download response is to use HTTP Headers, e.g:

```
return new HttpResult(fileInfo) {
    Headers = {
      {"X-key", "value"}
    }
};
```

Another option would be to embed the contents of the file inside a DTO:

```
class FileResponseWithMetadata
{
    public byte[] Data { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
}
```

For returning multiple files you'd need to zip the files using a library like [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) and return that instead.